# Constant Contact - Update Contact

Tags: c#, asp.net, constantcontact

I am trying to update a contact which already exists in my list by using 
**Utility.UpdateContactFullForm(authenticationData, contact);**

However, I get an error message stating:
**The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.**

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

**Source Error:** 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

I have referenced the **ConstantContactBO.dll** and the **ConstantContactUtility;**

I can't seem to figure out the problem, any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using ConstantContactBO;
using ConstantContactUtility;


public partial class hmm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string nextChunkId;
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        //Authentication Data
        AuthenticationData authenticationData = new AuthenticationData();
        authenticationData.Username = "";
        authenticationData.Password = "";
        authenticationData.ApiKey = "";

        // get user Contact List collection
        IList<ContactList> lists = Utility.GetUserContactListCollection(authenticationData, out nextChunkId);

        //Search for Contact By Email
        string x = "a@a.com";
        string[] emailAddress = new string[] { x.Trim() };
        IList<Contact> myList = Utility.SearchContactByEmail(authenticationData, emailAddress, out nextChunkId);

        for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
        {
            contact.Id = myList[0].Id;
            contact.FirstName = Server.HtmlEncode("abc");
            contact.LastName = Server.HtmlEncode("def");
            contact.EmailAddress = Server.HtmlEncode("a@a.com");

            ContactOptInList theList = new ContactOptInList();
            theList.OptInSource = ContactOptSource.ActionByContact;
            theList.ContactList = new ContactList("39");
            contact.ContactLists.Add(theList);
              Utility.UpdateContactFullForm(authenticationData, contact);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had missed out on including the following:

```
 Contact thisContact = Utility.GetContactDetailsById(authenticationData, myContact[0].Id);
           // //Add Lists
            ContactOptInList newList = new ContactOptInList();
            //thisContact.OptInSource = ContactOptSource.ActionByCustomer;
            newList.ContactList = new ContactList("39"); //Contact list you want to add them to
            newList.ContactList = new ContactList("10"); //Contact list you want to add them to
            thisContact.ContactLists.Add(newList);

            //Update contact
            Utility.UpdateContactFullForm(authenticationData, thisContact);
```